# How to move filestream pointer to particular line without parsing each line (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, parsing

I have a text file with huge data (More than 100000 lines)

How can I move my file pointer to particular line without parsing all the lines before that.

Using getline(), I have to parse each and every line and is time consuming when the file is too large.

Comment: Are your lines a regular size, or do they vary?

Comment: How are you supposed to know where the line ends if you don't parse it?

Comment: No, each line is of different length

Comment: Because a text file is just a sequential stream of characters, and since newlines can start anywhere, the answer is: you can't (because you don't know where the newlines are).

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov, there is a getline function which parses line by line. otherwise you have to find '\n' and do the same

Comment: Unless you encode your file in some way to know where the line ends before parsing it, it is impossible.

Comment: Consider, I have a file which has line endings

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov, line ending is not a problem. My question is, whether is there any solution to move file pointer to particular line without parsing each line. ex: using seek, I can directly go to end, beginning or any position of the file. But, to give position, is a problem.

Comment: If lines are note regulare, you need to index your file. your file must be parsed at least once and index the start of your lines <line_i, index_i>.
This indexing could be used in future uses.

Comment: As you were already told: no, unless you yourself store this information somewhere and parse it.

Comment: @Landstalker, yeah this is one of the solution. But, if there exists a file with more than 400000 lines (I have it in my case), and it affects initial performance to parse and store data.

Comment: @Bhargava you need to evaluate the benefit of this approach.
If you use your file a lot of times in an execution, indexing is essential.
If this is not the case, indexing will not be useful because its execution time will be greater than that of a classical sequential parsing.

Comment: @Bhargava simple question : Are your files constantly changing? or are they relatively stable in terms of content?

Comment: @Landstalker, file is constant. only one file is there at any moment. And yes I may access file content at any time for different data.

Comment: The root cause is that text lines are variable length records.  The best you can do is to read lines from the file, store the file positions into a container (`std::vector`).  When you want to seek to a line, fetch the position from the container, then seek to the file position.

Comment: @Bhargava in your place, I will create for each data file, another index file which I will load at the first execution of my program.
The update of my index files (second files) will be performed in the background and will be applied only to files whose content has changed, preferably when I am not using my program (night for exemple).
when launching my program, I load the index files into a data structure (map for example) and I open a descriptor on the data files to be able to move according to the content of my data structure (map for example) .
PS: I think a map can hold 400,000 entries

Comment: @Bhargava you don't have much choice because your files are very big and cannot be loaded entirely into memory

Comment: @Landstalker. Yes You are right. Currently using the same way. I will go in this way only as of now. Thank you

Comment: None of the comments here or in the question referenced above suggest the most obvious solution: pad all your lines to the max line length. Then you can get to any line with a single “seek” call

Comment: @VladFeinstein, the file will be generated by different person and is not in our control/we cannot ask and is in standard format. In this case, again padding and all we have to do our-self and it takes more time than reading offset of the whole file